# Which include path is used by g++ of Redhat Developer Toolset 7?

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++14, devtools

I am running Redhat Developer Toolset 7 on Centos 7. Centos 7 has gcc 4.8.2 installed by default and the include path for that compiler is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/include/
```

Devtoolset 7 provides g++ 7.3.1 and that compiler is found at:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++
```

I'm using VS Code with the cpptools extension to develop the code. I may need to specify the browse path for system header files to cpptools.

What is the include path for devtoolset 7?  I.e. where are the g++ 7.3.1 header files found (or are the 4.8.2 header files used)?

Answer (score 0):

The include paths are shown by:

```
cpp -v
```